# Variable Time Parameter Javascript TimeOut

Tags: javascript, html

I am attempting to make a slideshow that would have a variable time for each picture. I am relatively new to Javascript and have been trying to fix this problem for awhile.

```
/*
function ShowEffect(element){
    new Effect.Appear(element,
    {duration:1, from:0, to:1.0});
    }
function FadeEffect(element){
    new Effect.Fade(element,
    {duration:1, from:1.0, to:0});
    }
*/
//starting value for variable i
var i = 0;


var slideImages = [
{name:"images/Blazer1.jpeg", type:"img", next: 6000}, 
{name:"images/grabbers.jpg", type:"img", next: 6000}, 
{name:"images/BlazerMan.gif", type:"gif", next: 6000},
{name:"images/threading.jpg", type:"img", next: 6000}];




/*function myTimeout essentially tells the slideshow to go to the next slide */
function myTimeout(){

 setTimeout(slideShow()}, slideImages[i].next) 

 }  
/*vidImg is used in hiding the images so video can be shown or
hiding video so the image can be shown */
function vidImg() {
if(slideImages[i].type == "img")
{
        document.getElementById("slide").style.display="block"; 
        document.getElementById("gif").style.display="none";
}
else if(slideImages[i].type == "gif")
{
        document.getElementById("slide").style.display="none"; 
        document.getElementById("gif").style.display="block";
}
}



/* slideShow function is where the slideShow knows to go to the next slide
or to return to the first slide */








    function slideShow() 

    { 

    if(slideImages[i].type == "img") {
    document.slide.src = slideImages[i].name;
    vidImg();}
    else{
    document.getElementById("gif").src = slideImages[i].name;
    vidImg();}



    if(i < slideImages.length -1) {
          i++;
          }

     else {i = 0;}; 
     /*
     setTimeout("FadeEffect('hideshow')", 4000);

     setTimeout("ShowEffect('hideshow')",5000);
     */

     myTimeout();




     } 


     /*tells the browser to automatically run slideShow when window is opened */

     window.onload= slideShow;
```

Unfortunately the result is can be very random. Not to sure what is going on. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check your bracers here:

```
function myTimeout(){

 setTimeout(slideShow()}, slideImages[i].next) 

 }
```

Maybe it should be:

```
function myTimeout(){
     setTimeout(slideShow(), slideImages[i].next);
}
```

If it was just a typo then check that you are not modifying `i` anywhere else.